# How to make mysql ```UNIX_TIMESTAMP()``` return custom timestamp?

Tags: python, mysql, pytest

For simplicity `pytest` launches `my_server` and `mysql_server` (inside docker). `my_server` connects to `mysql_server` (over host network), then he gets value of `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();` from `mysql_server` process it to day of week, then prints number according to day of week:

```
('mon', 1667768400), # print 1
('tue', 1667854800), # print 2
('wed', 1667941200), # print 3
...
```

I'm looking for something like this, but I want to change it globally for all opened sessions:

```sql
-- one can connect to mysql and
-- change value for current session,
-- but I need to set it globally or
-- somehow change value for another
-- session.
-- for example for monday:

mysql> set session timestamp = 1667768400;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
+------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP() |
+------------------+
|       1667768400 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> set global timestamp = 1667768400;
ERROR 1228 (HY000): Variable 'timestamp' is a SESSION variable and can't be used with SET GLOBAL
```

Notes:

- I can't change code inside `my_server`, it's very expensive;
- I can't change host machine timestamp, because such an action would require to run tests with sudo, which is strange requirement for a test.

Kind regards,
Oleg

Comment: Your MySQL client opens a connection to MySQL. Each connection have a lot of properties. One of the properties is "additional command which is executed during the connection establishing". Find this property and add `set session timestamp` to its value.

Comment: just run tests with sudo; allow the command you need in a sudoers file.

Comment: No, I need this ```set session timestamp``` only for tests, ```my_server``` is a production service, which doesn't need this setting for a session.   
No, proposing any manipulations with host default time is a bad practice. I want to change database properties, I thought I made it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dare to suggest the idea of MySQL-proxy for modifying queries transmitted to the SQL server. You can look at this as a starting point: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-proxy

Comment: proxy is a good, flexible solution